# Responsive Custom Columns & DataTables

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, datatables

I have added two custom columns into DataTables. My problem is I am unsure how to hide the one on the far right when using the responsive layout and compensate for the one on the far left.

I have done it this way as I am using server sided code to feed in the data and this seemed to be the cleanest way of implementing it.

I have also tried implementing class control but it still seems to ignore the breaking points.

I have added them with the code below.

```
      //Customised Rows
      'fnCreatedRow': function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        //Add ID to Row
        $(nRow).attr('id', aData[0]);

        //New Custom Column Heading
        $(nRow).find('td').eq(0).before('<td>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="flat icheckbox_flat-green" name="table_records" value="'+aData[0]+'">' + '</td>');

        $(nRow).find('td').eq(-1).after('<td>' + '<a href="edit.php?'+aData[0]+'">Edit</a>' + '</td>');
      }

  //New Custom Column Heading
  $('thead').find('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('th').eq(0).before('<th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat"></th>');
  });

  $('thead').find('tr').each(function(){
      $(this).find('th').eq(-1).after('<th class="desktop">Edit</th>');
  });
```

You can find a working sample here: [Temporary page](http://www.cupoftshirt.co.uk/leads.php)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it feels like UX has a part to play in this question - what really is the best way to present the data? Should you make a scroll within the table itself? Should you do away with the columns and make rows only. Anyway, here is a link to open up a few ideas: https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

Comment: Thanks! That seems really useful ☺️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#datatable-leads").DataTable().columns()
```

Tells me the datable framework doesent seem to know about these new columns. It still thinks it has 7 columns while it has 9.

when you inisiate the datatable you can add a extensive configuration of the columns, here you can create additional columns.

```
var columns= [{data: "foo", title:"bar", render: function(data, type,full,meta) {
return '<input type="checkbox" class="flat icheckbox_flat-green" name="table_records" value="'+aData[0]+'">'}}]
$("#datatable-leads").DataTable({
   data:data,
   responsive: true,
   columns: columns
})
```

Hope this helps

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/m8psojk3/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed response! I am having a little trouble integrating this. Would you be willing to provide a a JS Fiddle?

Comment: Thanks very much. I have updated the file in the original post to try and get it working with server-side processing. I now have a problem where it is trying to pull all of the data into the first column.

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing that means you are sending the framework data in a different format then I did in my example. Probably as a fieldless array? Null points to the base of the array which is why you are getting the entire row in the data. What you can do then (If my assumptions are correct?) is reference the array position by its position in the array like this: jsfiddle.net/m8psojk3/2  .

Comment: One last question. Would it be possible to disable sorting on these two additional columns? I have tried using '"orderable": false' to no avail.

Comment: It should be possible, but datatables sort on the first column by default. Set it to order by a different column should solve the problem. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m8psojk3/3/